# Xcode 7.3 + Cocos2dx : Crash on Sprite Creation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x, xcode7.3

In Xcode 7.3 Cocos2dx returns null texture. Crashed for below line

```
Sprite  *container = Sprite::create("BG.png");
```

Image already added to Xcode. Same code runs perfect in Xcode 7.2
Its strange crash only happens in Xcode 7.3. Both in device and simulator.

libPNG returns NULL. How to fix this ?

Comment: Crashing on Simulator or real device or both ?

Comment: And there are no messages? no stacktrace?  If so, we cannot help.

Comment: @trojanfoe, libPNG returned NULL, I got simple solution, see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got simple Solution. Go to build settings in Xcode and set

```
Remove Text Metadata From PNG Files = NO
```

By default its set to YES. Make it NO

Comment: I've never had to do that with a Cocos2d-x project.  I seriously doubt this is the real answer.

Comment: Ok, but this fixed my crash. Now libPNG returned valid data.